# How to make Native Client Application single tenant in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, azure-active-directory, office365api

I've created a native client application in the Azure Active Directory, Developed a Xamarin Android app and using ADAL Library i can log in myapp using any Microsoft email account... BUT i want to choose my own domain Only (i have office365 subscription).

- the web application or web api have a checkbox choosing single or multi-tenant, but i cant find that in the native client application.
- i've tried to download the MANIFEST

  - changing "availableToOtherTenants" to false
  - changing "knownClientApplications" to my clientId
  - using https and http in the redirect url
  - tried almost anything that makes sense or not

but nothing happens, I still can log in to my app using any Microsoft account.

Should I make the restriction in my app after getting the logged in email??... i think that's very bad.

**More info...**

I've managed to do the following:

- changing MANIFEST "availableToOtherTenants" to "true"
- changing MANIFEST "knownClientApplications" to my ClientId
- calling the api with authority url: "https://login.windows.net/common" (not with my tenant id)

Result:

I can login with my domain only BUT any other Microsoft account throws an unhandled exception from the ADAL library (same as the unhandled exception if the user canceled logging in)

Answer (score 0):

All native clients in azure ad are automatically multi tenant. However you can initialize your AuthenticationContext with the authority of your own tenant (eg ) and only your own users will be able to get a token with it. On your web API you will have to check that users are coming only from that tenant, but that already happens automatically if you specify the tenant instead of common in the middleware initialization.

Comment: I've tried changing "common" to "<my-tenant-id>" in the authority url but unlike the web api i still can login using any Microsoft account

Comment: With "I can login" you mean that the user can enter their credentials, but you don't get back a token right?

Comment: the user enter their credentials and i do get back the token

Comment: Are those users guests in your tenant, or random MSA users? If the former, that's by design: those would be your users as much as native ones. If the latter, that does not sound right. Are you able to use the resulting token to successfully invoke the API?

Comment: No not guests... random users, and yes that does not sound right but i'm able to read the profile of the logged in user like firstname, lastname, uniqueid,.. (i didn't actually try to get more info)

Comment: That is stuff you get in the token, the key here is whether you can use the token for making calls too. Can you give me more details via the contact form on www.cloudidentity.com

Comment: Let me get that straight... if I used https://login.windows.net/<my-tenant-id> ... the user can login and i can get the token but i cant make further calls? even if the user agreed on any permissions i've declared?
all i want is to prevent the user from authenticating at all if not in my organization or a guest

Comment: Has anyone got this work? We are also having similar issue where we want to restrict users outside of our domain to use the native app feature.